# Help Identifying a Molex/MATE-N-LOCK style connector

Tags: identification, connector, plug, socket

Hoping someone can help as I've spent the last few hours trying to find this specific connector on a number of distribution and manufacturer sites.
The pitch looks like it is around 6.3mm.
It's a 2x2 layout similar to the standard Molex Mega-Fit range (or an oversized ATX connector) but has rounded bottom connectors (not square/corner cut ones) resembling what is available in the Molex MLX or MATE-N-LOCK range.
BUT I can't find this specific plug in either of their ranges.
[image: Unknown Connector]
The plug is used to connect accessories like sensors to industrial testing equipment so changing to a new standard isn't possible as it needs to be used in both new and existing equipment.
Any help would be much appreciated!